# Why was this Star Trek and slavery question locked?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Why was [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/239642/14850) locked? The [moderation banner at the top of the page on that question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/239642/14850) states:

> “Locked for 7 days. There are disputes about this question’s content being resolved at this time. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions.”

I am sure some people will say it is obvious that it is a touchy issue, but I don’t get it. From my viewing of the question right now I see no contention. I do see some great answers on that question and no signs of contention.

So what exactly is the “dispute” here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing to do with slavery being a touchy issue. If you check the [revision history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/239642/revisions), you'll see that the OP was repeatedly editing replies to comments into their post and rolling back attempts to remove them. Situations like this, commonly known as "rollback wars", usually require a moderator to step in and lock the post at a particular version until the editing/content dispute is resolved.

Comment: Are you not able to lock the question and leave the answers and comments open?

Comment: @Valorum Unfortunately, no; there are only a few types of lock available, and locking edits on a question also locks comments and answers. There's plenty of feature requests on main meta about improving the post locking functionality, if you want to go and support them.

Comment: Some mention of the reason for the lock on the question itself would likely be appropriate, especially as the question is currently in the Hot Network Questions list.

Comment: @R.M. I was going to leave a comment, but since the user is now suspended, I've just unlocked it instead.